# Где достать .ppk ключ Amazon Lightsail?

Tags: amazon, amazon-web-services

Я выбрал `Nginx + Amazon Linux`. Запустил перешел по SSH в окне браузера, все настроил. Но вот только я буду писать приложение с доступом по `SSH` и мне нужен ключ чтоб пройти аутентификацию, а ключ у меня только `.pem (default)` Putty и другие его не принимают. Где найти `.ppk` ключ я тоже не знаю, посмотреть логи я тоже не знаю где они находятся. В `EC2` всё пишется и логи, и ключ, и `enctyption` и т.д, а в `Lightsail` ничего нету. Где найти приватный ключ `.ppk` и просмотреть системный логи сервера как в EC2?

Answer (score 1):

Ключ нужно просто конвертировать в `.ppk` так как `.pem` от OpenSSH, а `.ppk` от Putty.

Comment: Причем конвертировать pem в ppk проще всего с помощью Putty